# Attach comment to post/table cell

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm working on a quotes app, where users can comment and like on each quote. I have successfully added a submit button for when the user wants to add a question but there's a problem; the same comments show up for every single table cell / post. I'm busying a code that attaching the comments to the post / cell clicked but I'm not sure what it is. Here's the code for the view controller with the submit comment textfield.

```
- (IBAction)submitClicked:(id)sender {

NSString *commentString = self.commentTitle.text;
PFObject *comment = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Comment"];
[comment setObject:commentString forKey:@"commentText"];
[comment saveInBackground];
[self disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

With this code, the comments show up under a class called 'Comment.' The posts on the other hand show up under a class called "Post."

How do I link both so the comments show up to specific posts / table cell?!

Answer (score 0):

You are not in any way associating the comment with the post.  The Comment class should have a column called post which would be the reference to the post it belongs to.  You would do something like this:

```
[comment setObject:post forKey:@"post"];
```

post in this case would be the PFObject you created for the post.

You can take a look at The Parse documentation for [Relations](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#relations).

When you want to then receive all the comments for a post, you would create a PFQuery for the Comment class and have something like the following as part of the query:

```
[commentQuery whereKey:@"post" equalTo:post];
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This now links it to the post on parse.com but the tableview that shows all the comments when the cell is clicked still shows all the comments. Here is the tableviewcontroller files: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxa9gKKM2SjSU2YwQzlLeFpFckE/view?usp=sharing :)

Comment: Hey, I just noticed a new post is added when I add a comment to a blank post, why is that?  - (IBAction)submitClicked:(id)sender {
 
    NSString *commentString = self.commentTitle.text;
    PFObject *comment = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Comment"];
    PFObject *post = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Post"];

    [comment setObject:commentString forKey:@"commentText"];
    [comment setObject:post forKey:@"post"];
    [comment setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.theRiverID] forKey:@"riverID"];
    [comment saveInBackground];
   }